# How to disable One Page Checkout on Mobile Magento 1.9.1

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0

I have installed ONE ONEPAGE CHECKOUT on my magento store 1.9.1 and it works great on desktop but on mobile devices is not clickable. How can i disable it only for mobile devices? I am very beginners so I will apreciate some help.

Thanks
Anna

Comment: Hi Anna, Magento already provides One Page checkout. And it will working fine over all devices. Can you please share complete name of extension you had installed over there.? So I would like to answer to you  in depth..

Comment: Hi Praful, I am using iwd One Step Checkout https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html.

Comment: which web service you have used for Mobile devices , ( SOAP , REST , XML RPC ) ,

Answer (score 0):

Install responsive one step checkout.You can download it from here
[One Step / Page Checkout](https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html)

OR

You need to disable one step checkout by identifying mobile device from code.

**UPDATE**

To identify mobile device

```
$mobile_agents = "/(nokia|iphone|ipod|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|"  
             . "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|"  
             . "blackberry|blackberry10|bb10|playbook|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|"  
             . "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|"  
             . "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220"  
             . ")/i";  
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match($mobile_agents, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
     // mobile device
}
```

Comment: Hi Minesh, can you explain how to identify mobile device from code ?

Comment: @Anna updated my answer to identify mobile device